# How can I run rspec inside rspec-mode?

Tags: emacs, rspec

I have a directory with files like this

```
.
├── example.rb
└── example_spec.rb
```

And my `init.el` :

```lisp
(require 'rspec-mode)
(setq-default rspec-use-rvm t)

(require 'rvm)
(rvm-use-default)
```

When I try to run any of the verify functions inside the `example_spec.rb` will result the error :

> rspec-project-root: Could not determine the project root.

How do I make `rspec-mode` able to *determine the project root* and run rspec ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at docstring of `rspec-project-root` it seems it looks for `Rakefile` in the presenst directory or a parent directory. Here is the docstring

```
Finds the root directory of the project by walking the directory tree until it 
finds a rake file.
```

The [code](https://github.com/pezra/rspec-mode/blob/master/rspec-mode.el#L634) suggests that a gem file will also do.

Comment: Thank you, I just add an empty `Rakefile` and it works now :)